# Why is the copy constructor called twice in this code snippet?

Tags: c++, c++14, copy-constructor

I'm playing around with a few things to understand how copy constructors work. But I can't make sense of why the copy constructor is called twice for the creation of `x2`. I would have assumed it would be called once when the return value of `createX()` is copied into `x2`.
I also looked at a few related questions on SO, but as far as I can tell I couldn't find the same simple scenario as I am asking here.

By the way, I'm compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors` in order to see what's going on without optimizations.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    int i{2};

    X() {
        std::cout << "default constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    X(const X& other) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor called" << std::endl;
    }
};

X createX() {
    X x;
    std::cout << "created x on the stack" << std::endl;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    X x1;
    std::cout << "created x1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x1: " << x1.i << std::endl << std::endl;    

    X x2 = createX();
    std::cout << "created x2" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x2: " << x2.i << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
default constructor called
created x1
x1: 2

default constructor called
created x on the stack
copy constructor called
copy constructor called
created x2
x2: 2
```

Can someone help me what I'm missing or overlooking here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you have to remember here is that the return value of a function is a distinct object.  When you do

```
return x;
```

you copy initialize the return value object with `x`.  This is the first copy constructor call you see.  Then

```
X x2 = createX();
```

uses the returned object to copy initialize `x2` so that is the second copy you see.

---

One thing to note is that

```
return x;
```

will try to move `x` into the return object if it can.  Had you made a move constructor you would have seen this called.  The reason for this is that since local objects go out of scope at the end of the function, the compiler treats the object as an rvalue and only if that does not find a valid overload does it fall back to returning it as an lvalue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah.  Updating the wording to make that more explicit that isn't something that is just allowed but has to be done.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details of `-fno-elide-constructors` but I'm assuming it prevents RVO.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It does not prevent guaranteed RVO if using C++17 since that is mandated that it has to happen, there isn't actually a temporary object created. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d1ae5a4e07e7d34) where it only uses a single copy as the second one is mandated not to happen.

Comment: So we have to assume OP is using a pre-C++17 standard?

Comment: Kind of.  The compiler they are using could have a bug, or they are using pre C++17.  I'm inclined to believe it is the latter.

Comment: Yes I'm using c++14. I didn't realize it would make a difference. Updated the post.

Answer (score 14):

First copy is in return of createX

```
X createX() {
    X x;
    std::cout << "created x on the stack" << std::endl;
    return x; // First copy
}
```

Second one is to create x2 from the temporary return by createX.

```
X x2 = createX(); // Second copy
```

Notice that in C++17, second copy is forced to be elided.